# How to get login user's document path in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf C# application, I want to get login user's my documents path.
I use the following code.

```
string myDocumentPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%"), "Documents");
```

But when run the wpf application with Run as Administrator, I got the Administrator's document path by using the above code.

Is there other funtion for this problem?
Please any idea or advice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` for getting environment folders. In particular, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`, which will give you the "My Documents" (now simply called "Documents") folder for the user that the application is running under.